# Edge Browser Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: asp.net-core, google-chrome, deployment, .net-6.0, iis-6

My web site cannot deploy IIS. Because of this error => chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1

My Browser Microsoft Edge

Error showing in browser like this.

This page isn’t working right now.
localhost can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

But inspect showing chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1

I can't deploy my ASP. Net core 6.0 MVC WEB APPLICATION because this.

I try deploying my application.

[enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTVYY.png)

I don't know if its application error. But application well run.

Comment: 500 error might be caused by anything,would you check the log for the detailed reason?

Comment: How I find Log for Details ???